# '^' Character Matches Both '<' and '>' in Python Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to match against `*=`, `&=`, `+=`, `-=`, `|=`, and `^=` in a regular expression, but for some reason the below pattern accepts both `<=` and `>=`:

```
modifyPat = re.compile('\s*[&\|\*/%\+-^]*=[^=]*')
```

I've done some digging, and found that the problem arises due to the inclusion of the `^` character in the pattern. If, for example, I remove the `^` as in the below pattern, I get expected matching behavior, but of course lose the ability match against `^=`:

```
modifyPat = re.compile('\s*[&\|\*/%\+-]*=[^=]*')
```

What is going on here, and is there any way to include the `^` character in order to match `^=` without also matching `<=` and `>=` as I'd desire?

Comment: Look at `[+-^]`, the hyphen must be at the end and `^` should not be at the beginning.

Comment: Also, use raw strings: `r'...'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way sets are defined has a lot of latitude, and a metasyntax of its own:

```
[+-^]
```

This means all the characters between `+` and `^` in the ASCII table, which is a lot of them and includes `<` and `>` as well as all letters.

To fix it:

```
[\+\-\^]
```

Escaping anything irregular is usually a good idea even if not strictly necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I almost never use character ranges, and for some reason forgot that the `-` was used for that purpose.

Comment: Regular expressions have a reputation for being notoriously tricky for precisely this reason.